# Problems with undefined control sequence in list of figures

Tags: biblatex, errors, captions

I'm using TeXLive 2011. I had a lot of problems with compiling my large document yesterday and finally seemed to have gotten back to a working version, however now I get strange error messages in the list of figures like

> [5 ./Diss.lof:61: Undefined control sequence.  ...skip
>   \abovedisplayskip \let \sml@listi 
>                                                     =\leftmargin \leftmargini ... l.61 ...S.~391]{Johannaber2004}}}{49}{figure.2.10}

or

> [5 ./Diss.lof:61: Undefined control sequence.  ...skip
>   \abovedisplayskip \let \sml@listi 
>                                                     =\leftmargin \leftmargini ... l.61 ...te [S.~6ff]{Starke2004}}}{51}{figure.2.10}

The corresponding code in the lof file looks like that:

```
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {\relax 2.10}{\ignorespaces Ursachen f\"ur Ma\IeC {\ss }abweichungen des Spritzgie\IeC {\ss }werkzeugs beim Kunststoffspritzguss nach~\textcite [S.~6ff]{Starke2004}}}{51}{figure.2.10}
```

I'm sorry, that at the moment I can not provide a minimal example,
can someone explain, what this undefined control sequences are about? It seems to be a  `cite` command in a caption.

**EDIT**

after Herbert's suggestion, I modified the source in the following way and removed all aux, lof, lot etc. files:

```
\caption[pure text without any command]{text with~\protect\textcite[][]{}}
```

But the problem persists:

> [5 ! Undefined control sequence.  ...skip \abovedisplayskip
>   \let \sml@listi 
>                                                     =\leftmargin \leftmargini ... l.61 ...te [S.~6ff]{Starke2004}}}{51}{figure.2.10}

I'm using the scrbook class (komascript). I'll try to set up a minimal example asap.

**EDIT:** a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \caption[Bar \protect\textcite[][]{aksin}]{Foo \protect\textcite[][]{aksin}}
\end{figure}
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

resulting in:

```
(./x.aux) (./x.bbl) (./x.lof
! Argument of \blx@citeargs@i has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.2 ...line {1}{\ignorespaces Bar \textcite [}}{1}

?
```

where the lof file is this:

```
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces Bar \textcite [}}{1}
\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax
```

Comment: I've gotten a similar issue when a caption uses commands that I've defined in another file. Getting rid of those fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after long testing, comparison of version history etc. I finally found that the error seemed to come from a completely different piece of code somewhere else (in the preamble, where I had not expected it):

I wanted to change the size of `fixme´ annotations to`small` and tried like that

```
\usepackage[draft, silent=true]{fixme}
\fxsetup{theme=color, inline, targetlayout=color, author=}
\newcommand{\N}[1]{\mbox{}\fxfatal*[inline=true,nomargin]{\small\sffamily/#1/}{}}
```

Apparently that led to mysterious problems like the one above.

Answer (score 6):

use `\protect\textcite{}` in your caption or better

```
\caption[entry for the lof without (!) \textcite]{... \protect\textcite{...} ...}
```

and delete the `*.lof` file for the next run otherwise you'll get always the same error again.

Comment: thank you. I'm just confused, because I've been using `cite` and `citet` and also `citeauthor` for a long time in captions without any problem (and without `\protect`). Is there any difference between them and `\textcite` (`biblatex` package)?

Comment: the \protect does not solve the problem, see my edit

Comment: yes, I deleted all auxiliary files before the next runs. The problem occurs in the 2nd pdflatex run.

Comment: delete the cite command, delete all auxiliary files and run pdflatex twice. Did you get the error?

Comment: I did so and the error persists, the LOF now looks like `\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {\relax 2.10}{\ignorespaces Ursachen f\"ur Ma\IeC {\ss }abweichungen des Spritzgie\IeC {\ss }werkzeugs beim Kunststoffspritzguss}}{51}{figure.2.10}`

Comment: That line cannot be the problem and there is no other way than creating a minimal example. Move the `\end{document}` up until the error is gone.

Comment: it seems I've found the root of the problem in the preamble (see my answer) Thank you very much for your help and your patience! Sorry for having led you to a wrong path with the `cite` command in the captions.

Comment: Is there really no way to get `\textcite` included in the short text of a caption for the LoF?

Comment: With `\protect\textcite{FooBar2009}` I get it compiled, but with `\protect\textcite[][Fig.~9]{FooBar2009}` it complains with `! Argument of \blx@citeargs@i has an extra }.`